# Retrieve column values based on matches between another column with a column in a second matrix

Tags: r

I want to replace `rownames(normal.meth)` with the corresponding values in `meth.anno$geneNames` if the existing `rownames(normal.meth)` match `meth.anno$probeID`. Both matrices are unordered.

```
rownames(normal.meth) <- meth.anno[rownames(normal.meth) %in% meth.anno$probeID,]$geneNames
```

Traceback:

```
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

Input

```
> dput(normal.meth[1:5,1:5])
structure(c(0.515455282880639, 0.97045870602927, 0.901165700394357, 
0.162692440621765, 0.89710904117382, 0.343674708139333, 0.972888059373319, 
0.915128518830134, 0.138548281248091, 0.92038340114066, 0.489442046194044, 
0.953176398928738, 0.9335837684512, 0.10877780962314, 0.908916456368568, 
0.578367183337139, 0.974767379272895, 0.913897835838841, 0.113012642325218, 
0.903143353383053, 0.547287820003221, 0.956942802183765, 0.897469710684965, 
0.146303108636092, 0.933600786692477), dim = c(5L, 5L), dimnames = list(
    c("cg00000029", "cg00000108", "cg00000109", "cg00000165", 
    "cg00000236"), c("TCGA.A4.7288.11", "TCGA.BQ.5880.11", "TCGA.BQ.5879.11", 
    "TCGA.BQ.5883.11", "TCGA.BQ.7055.11")))

> dput(meth.anno[1:5,])
structure(list(CpG_chrm = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1"
), CpG_beg = c(15864L, 18826L, 29406L, 29424L, 29434L), CpG_end = c(15866L, 
18828L, 29408L, 29426L, 29436L), probe_strand = c("-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-"), probeID = c("cg00000109", "cg00000165", "cg12045430", 
"cg20826792", "cg00381604"), genesUniq = c("WASH7P", "MIR6859-1;WASH7P", 
"MIR1302-2;MIR1302-2HG;WASH7P", "MIR1302-2;MIR1302-2HG;WASH7P", 
"MIR1302-2;MIR1302-2HG;WASH7P"), geneNames = c("WASH7P", "WASH7P", 
"WASH7P", "WASH7P", "WASH7P"), transcriptTypes = c("unprocessed_pseudogene", 
"miRNA;unprocessed_pseudogene", "miRNA;lncRNA;lncRNA;unprocessed_pseudogene", 
"miRNA;lncRNA;lncRNA;unprocessed_pseudogene", "miRNA;lncRNA;lncRNA;unprocessed_pseudogene"
), transcriptIDs = c("ENST00000488147.1", "ENST00000619216.1;ENST00000488147.1", 
"ENST00000607096.1;ENST00000469289.1;ENST00000473358.1;ENST00000488147.1", 
"ENST00000607096.1;ENST00000469289.1;ENST00000473358.1;ENST00000488147.1", 
"ENST00000607096.1;ENST00000469289.1;ENST00000473358.1;ENST00000488147.1"
), distToTSS = c("13706", "-1390;10744", "-959;-860;-147;164", 
"-941;-842;-129;146", "-931;-832;-119;136"), CGI = c(NA, NA, 
"CGI:chr1:28735-29737", "CGI:chr1:28735-29737", "CGI:chr1:28735-29737"
), CGIposition = c(NA, NA, "Island", "Island", "Island")), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Dimensions

```
> dim(meth.anno)
[1] 423686     12

> dim(normal.meth)
[1] 486427     45
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `match()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the match, and replace as follows

```
m = meth.anno$geneNames[match(rownames(normal.meth), meth.anno$probeID)]
rownames(normal.meth)[!is.na(m)] <- m[!is.na(m)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code

```r
rownames(normal.meth)[which(rownames(normal.meth) %in% meth.anno$probeID)] <- meth.anno$geneNames[which(rownames(normal.meth) %in% meth.anno$probeID)]
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
           TCGA.A4.7288.11 TCGA.BQ.5880.11 TCGA.BQ.5879.11 TCGA.BQ.5883.11 TCGA.BQ.7055.11
cg00000029       0.5154553       0.3436747       0.4894420       0.5783672       0.5472878
cg00000108       0.9704587       0.9728881       0.9531764       0.9747674       0.9569428
WASH7P           0.9011657       0.9151285       0.9335838       0.9138978       0.8974697
WASH7P           0.1626924       0.1385483       0.1087778       0.1130126       0.1463031
cg00000236       0.8971090       0.9203834       0.9089165       0.9031434       0.9336008
```

Comment: This does not replace something in `rownames(normal.meth)`.

Comment: please check the updated code